# Show / Hide Function within while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a while loop that spits out data from some advanced custom fields.

Within the while loop I have a read more / read less button that displays an additional field if clicked.

The problem I have is there is no unique ID for the div, so when clicking the read more button all of the sections open, not just the one I selected.

The html looks like this -

```
<?php if(have_rows('features')) : ?>

<div class="features-container">

<?php while(have_rows('features')) : the_row(); ?>

<div class="feature">

    <?php if(get_row_index() % 2 == 0) : ?>
        <div class="feature-image" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>');">
            <div class="categories-tag-left"><?php the_sub_field('category'); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="feature-description">
        <div class="featured-description-container">
            <h3><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></h3>
            <?php the_sub_field('introduction'); ?></br>
            <div class="slidingDiv">
                <?php the_sub_field('more'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="read-more-button-container">
                <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php if(get_row_index() % 2 != 0) : ?>
        <div class="feature-image" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>');">
            <div class="categories-tag-right"><?php the_sub_field('category'); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The JavaScript I have looks like this -

```
$(".slidingDiv").hide();

$('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    var val = $(this).text() == "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
    $(this).hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` button you used) are for **runnable** examples using browser technologies. PHP isn't a browser technology. The best way to ask your question would be to use a Stack Snippet, but without the PHP and *with* a few example rows as they would be when sent to the browser.

Comment: Accepting answers is a great way to motivate users to provide useful answers on your future questions, **and** it increase your reps., which also will help you get more out of being a user here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You know which `.show_hide` button was clicked because it will be `this` in the handler. So you just need to find the `.slidingDiv` associated with that button. They're both in a `.feature-description` container, so that's a fairly clear way to do it, via `closest` and `find`:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".feature-description").find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    var val = $this.text() == "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
    $this.hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Side note: Rather than `$(".slidingDiv").hide();`, which will allow them to show briefly causing a flash on the page as it loads, I'd recommend using CSS: `.slidingDiv { display: none; }`. (jQuery's `slideToggle` will then override that when you open the div.)

Live example:

```js
$('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(".feature-description").find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
    var val = $this.text() == "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
    $this.hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.slidingDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-container">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-description">
            <div class="featured-description-container">
                <h3>Feature 1 Name</h3>
                Feature 1 introduction</br>
                <div class="slidingDiv">
                    More about feature 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
                <div class="read-more-button-container">
                    <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-description">
            <div class="featured-description-container">
                <h3>Feature 2 Name</h3>
                Feature 2 introduction</br>
                <div class="slidingDiv">
                    More about feature 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
                <div class="read-more-button-container">
                    <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-description">
            <div class="featured-description-container">
                <h3>Feature 3 Name</h3>
                Feature 3 introduction</br>
                <div class="slidingDiv">
                    More about feature 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
                <div class="read-more-button-container">
                    <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="feature-description">
            <div class="featured-description-container">
                <h3>Feature 4 Name</h3>
                Feature 4 introduction</br>
                <div class="slidingDiv">
                    More about feature 4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
                <div class="read-more-button-container">
                    <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` for current node  and jquery functions like `prev` and `parent` to selecting desired element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();

$('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
$(this).parent().prev().slideToggle("slow");
var val = $(this).text() == "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
$(this).hide().text(val).fadeIn("fast");
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```